# Column 'XXXX' cannot convert between unicode and non unicode data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, oracle19c

We have Microsoft SQL Server 2017 based SSIS packages which make a connection to an Oracle 19c database. The packages were developed earlier using Visual Studio 2015 32-bit version.

We are in the process of upgrading to SQL Server 2019 and these packages need to be migrated using latest version of Visual Studio 2022.

When we are trying to make connection to the Oracle 19c database by executing the packages imported into Visual Studio 2022 64 bit, we get an error from the source Oracle 19c table related to conversion of non-unicode to unicode character data types.

- For Oracle source: `VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)`
- For SQL Server target: `NVARCHAR(200 BYTE)`

The national character set of the source Oracle database set as shown below:

```
NLS_LANGUAGE AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY AUSTRALIA
NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1
```

We can connect to the Oracle database via Oracle SQL Developer without any issues. Also, we have the SSIS package setting `Run64BitRuntime = False`.

We tried setting `NLS_LANG` as environment variable in client machine based on above character set but that didn't help. This is described in oracle article as below

https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/960508_1.html

Could you please suggest what is causing the issue and what needs to be done to pull data from the Oracle database in unicode data type?

Tried Oracle client 19c 32 bit and 64 bit in local machine

Comment: It is because source is VARCHAR and destination is NVARCHAR.  You can add a data transform in your data flow task to convert from VARCHAR to NVARCHAR

Comment: On Microsoft SQL Server the `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` data types by default use UCS-2 encoding, consuming two bytes per code point. (When *_SC, or Supplementary Character, collations are in use then UTF-16 encoding applies.) i.e.: `NVARCHAR(200 BYTE)` only allows for 100 code points to be stored from your `VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)` source on Oracle regardless of which character set it's using.